# Javascript, jquery, ajax url query string rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, url

I thought this would be easy but I guess I was wrong. I have a url;

> http://www.example.com/aa/bb.html?uid=123

using javascript jquery and html, I am able to retrieve data from a json api with the uid in the sample url above. However, I don't want that url displayed like that in the address bar after the data has been parsed. Rather, I need it to display as;

> http://www.example.com/aa/item-title

where `item-title`is the title of the data referenced by `uid=123.`

A php mod-rewrite would have been ideal, but this project does not make use of server side scripting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: mod-rewrite is not PHP - its an apache extension ... what HTTP server are you using ? -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: short of redirecting the user to an "exisiting" url ie: `http://www.example.com/aa/item-title` I'm pretty sure you cant do this client-side. Unless you can store the `uid` in a hash ie: `bb.html#uid=123` then you can remove the hash once you've gotten the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you change or modify the URL then the browser try to fetch data fro the new URL. You can do something with the part of URL after # mark.

Like :
http://www.example.com/aa/bb.html?uid=123#old_part

to
http://www.example.com/aa/bb.html?uid=123#newpart

I can see only one solution to your problem as you don't want to use mod_rewrite. You can redirect from first page just changing the URL based on the given `uid` value to the next page you want to display.

1. First page - read parameter `uid` and build the redirect URL based on the title(not any other stuff in your first URL page)
2. Redirect to the built URL
3. In redirected page do the rest of page specific stuff.